# HTTPS for GitLab on Google Compute Engine

Tags: gitlab, google-compute-engine

I'm trialling GitLab on GCE to see if it'll be more manageable instead of my own hosting elsewhere.

One requirement is for all traffic to be secure i.e. over SSH (for git operations) or https for web browsing (i.e. gitlab usage through the browser). I cannot seem to see where to provide keys etc (even if they're self-signed) so I can enable HTTPS traffic to gitlab. Yes, HTTPS traffic is enabled for the VM instance.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL for https is usually activated by a dedicated web server put in front of GitLab, one which provides https transport.

See for instance [`lib/support/nginx/gitlab-ssl`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab-ssl), which describe an **[nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main)** configuration redirecting https traffic to GitLab.

```
## HTTPS host
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
  server_name YOUR_SERVER_FQDN; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.com
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;
```

For a GCE, se for example "[Setting up a small web server on Google's Compute Engine — Part 2](https://blog.hdurer.net/posts/2014/04/16_setting-up-a-small-web-server-on-googles-compute-engine-part-2.html)".

Comment: It soon dawned on me that really I've actually just deployed a GCE VM instance with GitLab "preinstalled" -- so yes, an HTTP server would need to sit in front of it! I'll accept this answer instead of deleting entirely, as it may help others. Thank you!